# Soap response iteration in java

Tags: java, soap, soap-client

I am using java soap request and response in my code. I am getting the request and response properly. 
But I am not able to iterate the response
Please see my response and code used to iterate below.  Please help me to resolve this issue.

Response

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Body>
    <GetUserResponse xmlns="http://XXXX.com/XXXXXXXX.XXXXXXX.WS">
      <GetUserResult>
        user
          <PersonID>111113</PersonID>
          <Username>0987654321</Username>
          <Password />         
          <FwyMember>Y</FwyMember>
          <WebMember>Y</WebMember>
          <FirstName>Mohamed</FirstName>
          <Tier>firstclass</Tier>
          <CountryOfResidence>IN</CountryOfResidence>
          <PreferencesChanged>false</PreferencesChanged>       
          <FamilyRelationship />
          <Title>Mr</Title>
          <MiddleName />
          ........ continue like this
```

Java code

```
SOAPBody responseBody = response.getSOAPBody();
QName bodyName1 = new QName("http://XXXX.com/XXXXXXXX.XXXXXXX.WS","GetUserResponse");
java.util.Iterator iterator = responseBody.getChildElements(bodyName1);
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
  SOAPBodyElement responseElement = (SOAPBodyElement)iterator.next();
  String val = responseElement.getValue();
  System.out.println("The values are "+val);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I am not able to iterate the response". Are you getting any error? Are you seeing any unexpected behaviour? what is it?

Comment: I am not getting any error and also no output is printing on the screen.

Answer (score 2):

There is only one `GetUserResponse` element below `Body`. `getChildElements` only gets child elements, as opposed to descendant elements. You must first reach `GetUserResponse` and then iterate over *its* children.

Comment: Thanks for you update I have done the iteration using childnodes.